# Annotate block in Proteus

Tags: digital-logic, proteus, cad

How can I annotate a block in Proteus 8 (automatically)? For example, let's suppose I design a multiplexer and I embed it in a block and I need to copy it several times. How can I make Proteus annotate this block sequentially, instead of me writing MUX0, MUX1, etc.?

P.S.:I know how to do this with components, such as gates, but I don't get how to proceed with blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select your block, then click with right button like in the picture shown bellow

[image: Block Copy option]

Proteus automatically will copy the block and it will show the copied block in some sort of degraded view like the image shown bellow (attached to the mouse cursor)

[image]

then finally you can make a left click on any place of the sheet where you want to place the new block, isis will annotate it automatically for you like in the image shown bellow where connectors J1 and J1-1 were copied and named J11 and J12 respectively (on the left side of the sheet).

[image]

I hope I could help you

Comment: So the option was "Copy block". I was using "Copy to clipboard"... That really helped me. Thank you!

Comment: For nothing, I'm glad I could help you